# GCP - How to filter for boot disk using gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to run `gcloud compute instances list` on a project and only get a list of instances using a specific boot disk or image.
What I am currently running is:

```
gcloud compute instances list --project=my-project --filter="disks.initializeParams.sourceImage='image-name'"
```

However this is returning 0 items, moreover any filter I run into initializeParams returns 0 items. Am I doing something wrong with my filtering? Or is there a better way to get a list of instances using a specific image?

Comment: Information about which image was used during the creation of a GCE VM instance can be retrieved with a [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/describe) `gcloud compute disks describe DISK-NAME`. The image name will be listed next to `sourceImage` and the id next to `sourceImageId`.

Comment: As per [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances) disks[].boot indicate that this is a boot disk. The virtual machine will use the first partition of the disk for its root filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

Using only `gcloud`:

```sh
gcloud compute disks list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(users[].basename(),sourceImage.scope())"
```

Answer (score 1):

To find which source images were used while creating instances you can follow steps below:

1. Get list of GCE VM instances.

```
$ gcloud compute instances list
NAME        ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP      STATUS
instance-1  us-central1-a  e2-medium                  10.128.0.47  35.192.46.67     RUNNING
instance-2  us-central1-a  e2-medium                  10.128.0.48  104.197.166.219  RUNNING
instance-3  us-central1-a  e2-medium                  10.128.0.49  34.123.122.184   RUNNING
instance-4  us-central1-a  e2-medium                  10.128.0.50  35.222.216.107   RUNNING
```

2. Get data associated with disks (disk names are usually the same as GCE VM instance names; you can find `sourceImageId`s in the same way as `sourceImage`):

```
$ gcloud compute disks describe instance-1 --zone us-central1-a | grep sourceImage:
sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-10-buster-v20210122

$ gcloud compute disks describe instance-2 --zone us-central1-a | grep sourceImage:
sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-10-buster-v20210122

$ gcloud compute disks describe instance-3 --zone us-central1-a | grep sourceImage:
sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-7-v20210122

$ gcloud compute disks describe instance-4 --zone us-central1-a | grep sourceImage:
sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/global/images/custom-image-1
```

3. Filter results manually:

```
VM         SOURCE IMAGE
instance-1 debian-10-buster-v20210122
instance-2 debian-10-buster-v20210122
instance-3 centos-7-v20210122
instance-4 custom-image-1
```

Also, you can write some script, here an example for GCE VMs in same zone `us-central1-a`:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

vms=( $(gcloud compute instances list | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v NAME) )

for (( i = 0; i < ${#vms[@]} ; i++ )); do
    printf "${vms[$i]} "
    eval "gcloud compute disks describe ${vms[$i]} --zone us-central1-a | grep sourceImage: | awk '{print $2}'"
done

$ ./script.sh
instance-1 sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-10-buster-v20210122
instance-2 sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-10-buster-v20210122
instance-3 sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-7-v20210122
instance-4 sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/global/images/custom-image-1

$ ./script.sh | grep debian | awk '{print $1}'
instance-1
instance-2
```

Also, you can look on API requests.

Answer (score 0):

Start to perform a search in JSON mode like this

```
gcloud compute instances list --format=json
```

Then, focus on the field that you search for, and copy the JSON path to your filter (don't worry about array or not, put dot to create the hierarchy). Like this (for example)

```
gcloud compute instances list --format=json \
  --filter="disks.licenses=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/licenses/debian-10-buster"
```